# The difference between mempool "bytes" and "usage"

Tags: bitcoin-core, mempool

`getmempoolinfo` returns `bytes` and `usage`. Currently, the value I have for `bytes` is `1316363` and the value I have for `usage` is `4826112`.

I'm assuming that `bytes` is how much space these transactions would require if they were to be included in a block while `usage` is the size they are currently taking on my computer. That would imply that the transactions get compressed somehow (or some nonessential info gets stripped away) before they're included in a block. Is that correct or am I way off?

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

```
  "bytes": xxxxx,              (numeric) Sum of all virtual transaction sizes as defined in BIP 141. Differs from actual serialized size because witness data is discounted
  "usage": xxxxx,              (numeric) Total memory usage for the mempool
```

`bytes` is the size as calculated as vBytes as would be considered for inclusion in a block, `usage` is the logical size in actual bytes that are consuming memory.